# Display a LinkedHashMap list

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a problem displaying the data right. I have an sql query that returns the following data:

```
| count (long) | country  (string)|
---------------| ------------------
| 6            | null             |
| 3            | spain            |
| 6            | italy            |
```

And I have the following method:

```java
private Map<String, Long> countryCount (List<CountryCount> summary) {
    Map<String, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
    summary.forEach(sum -> {
      var country= sum.getCountry(); 
      if (country == null) {
        country= "unknown";
      }
      var count = result.get(country);
      if (count == null) {
        count = 0L;
      }
      result.put(country, count + sum.getCount());
    });
    return result.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
  }
```

In my method I want to return an object like `{"unknown" : 5, "spain" : 3, "italy" : 6}` but instead I get `{"unknown" : 15}`

Comment: Your code return `{italy=6, spain=3, unknown=6}`

Comment: You code is pretty specific as to when it will set country to unknown.  If not you have not already done so, make sure that the CountCount instances are being constructed properly (i.e. you are actually capturing the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this simpler code.

```java
Map < String, Long > map =
        listOfCountryCount
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCountry() ) ? "unknown" : countryCount.getCountry() ,
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCount() ) ? Long.valueOf( 0 ) : countryCount.getCount()
                        )
                );
```

If you want a sorted map, pass that map to constructor of a `SortedMap` or `NavigableMap` implementation.

```
NavigableMap< String , Long > mapNav = new TreeMap<>( map ) ;
```

Full example code.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List < CountryCount > listOfCountryCount = List.of(
                new CountryCount( "Peru" , 17L ) ,
                new CountryCount( "Xanadu" , 128L ) ,
                new CountryCount( null , 42L ) ,
                new CountryCount( "Andorra" , null )
        );

        Map < String, Long > map =
                listOfCountryCount
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(
                                        countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCountry() ) ? "unknown" : countryCount.getCountry() ,
                                        countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCount() ) ? Long.valueOf( 0 ) : countryCount.getCount()
                                )
                        );
        NavigableMap < String, Long > mapNav = new TreeMap <>( map );  // Keys are maintained in sorted order.

        System.out.println( "listOfCountryCount = " + listOfCountryCount );
        System.out.println( "map = " + map );
        System.out.println( "mapNav = " + mapNav );
    }
}

final class CountryCount
{
    private final String country;
    private final Long count;

    CountryCount ( String country , Long count )
    {
        this.country = country;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getCountry ( ) { return country; }

    public Long getCount ( ) { return count; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( CountryCount ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.country , that.country ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.count , that.count );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( country , count );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "CountryCount[" +
                "country=" + country + ", " +
                "count=" + count + ']';
    }
}
```

When run.

```
listOfCountryCount = [CountryCount[country=Peru, count=17], CountryCount[country=Xanadu, count=128], CountryCount[country=null, count=42], CountryCount[country=Andorra, count=null]]
map = {Andorra=0, Xanadu=128, Peru=17, unknown=42}
mapNav = {Andorra=0, Peru=17, Xanadu=128, unknown=42}
```

If you are not sure about your data being distinct, let's add a third argument to that [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) call. We pass a lambda function to be called in case of duplicate keys. In our case here, we go with a policy of first occurrence wins.

```java
Map < String, Long > map =
        listOfCountryCount
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCountry() ) ? "unknown" : countryCount.getCountry() ,
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCount() ) ? Long.valueOf( 0 ) : countryCount.getCount() ,
                                ( existing , replacement ) -> existing   // In case of duplicate key conflict, first one wins.
                        )
                );
```

We can shorten this code further. Rather than create a `TreeMap` separately, we can pass a constructor method reference as a fourth argument to our [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)): `TreeMap :: new`. And we change the declaration of the returned map from `Map` to `NavigableMap`.

```java
NavigableMap < String, Long > map =
        listOfCountryCount
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCountry() ) ? "unknown" : countryCount.getCountry() ,
                                countryCount -> Objects.isNull( countryCount.getCount() ) ? Long.valueOf( 0 ) : countryCount.getCount() ,
                                ( existing , replacement ) -> existing ,  // In case of duplicate key conflict, first one wins.
                                TreeMap :: new 
                        )
                );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4ujNNb).

```
listOfCountryCount = [CountryCount[country=Peru, count=17], CountryCount[country=Xanadu, count=128], CountryCount[country=null, count=42], CountryCount[country=Andorra, count=null]]
map = {Andorra=0, Peru=17, Xanadu=128, unknown=42}
```